# downloading Anaconda Individual edition

Tags: anaconda

Downloading the latest version or several from the archive, all give me the message "this version will not work on your pc".
I have a Dell XPS 8930 running on Windows 10 Home Version 21H1 OS build 19043.1348 with 312GB free storage.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you had posted the link you have tried and what steps you did for installation. Try [this link](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64.exe)

Comment: link used www.anaconda.com/distribute

Comment: I cannot access that link, it doesn't seem to exist. Try the link I have posted

Comment: sorry - typo - www.anaconda.com/distribution